# why in spring 3.1 id attribute is changed to xsd:string type?

Tags: spring

what the problem with spring 3.0 when i write id value as duplicate then we will get saxParseException but using spring 3.1 we are getting exception by springcontainer,
what is the advantage of it wheather exception is thrown by springcotainer or saxparserException exception is exception?then why they make id as xsd-string in place id ID datatype??

Answer (score 1):

Spring 3.1 changed the id from being an `xsd:ID` type to `string` due to [the introduction of profiles](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7508).

For profiles to work in xml you can add multiple `beans` elements which are all activated on a certain profile. Now this would fail if the `id` attribute would still be a `xsd:ID` type.

```
<beans>
    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <beans profile="test">
         <bean id="dataSource">
         </bean>
    </beans>
    <beans profile="prod">
         <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" />
    </beans>
</beans>
```

The (psuedo) code snippet above wouldn't work if id was still `xsd:ID` because one of the constraints is that it has to be unique. However `dataSource` is there twice. To fix this it needed to be a `string`.

And not (as I commented earlier) to allow for placeholders to work in id fields).